# Dynamic php og meta tags cant be accessed by facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <?php
      $th = $_GET['th'];
    ?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta property="og:title" content="Test"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php "/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Rapsodia Verano 15'"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Test"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/img/lookbook/<?php print $th; ?> "/>

    <title>Rapsodia 2015</title>    

  </head>
  <body>

    <img src="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/img/lookbook/<?php echo $th; ?>">

  </body>
</html>
```

If I enter this:

`http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php?th=09.jpg`

at

`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/`

I get

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Test" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php " />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Rapsodia Verano 15&#039;" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Test" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/img/lookbook/ " />
```

for some reason the php variable is not making its way in to the facebook server :(

If I go to `http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php?th=09.jpg`

manually everything works just fine :(

---

How can I make this work? I really dont know what else to try. I really must have dynamic og tags or else I will probably get fired or something.

Comment: The problem is that you specify og:url to http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php . Which means that we will go and fetch that url and present those tags.

Comment: But rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php  is actually the html file I pasted first, and in it you can see how php should output a variable in og:image... it works if u navigate to the site but it does not work when facebook gets there... maybe i am not clear enough edit: thanks for answering!

Comment: Make it so when you go to http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php?th=09.jpg og:url say http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php?th=09.jpg . If you do that it will work

Comment: a thousand times thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <?php
      $th = $_GET['th'];
    ?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta property="og:title" content="Test"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/admin/shares.php?th=<?php print $th; ?>  "/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Rapsodia Verano 15'"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Test"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/img/lookbook/<?php print $th; ?> "/>

    <title>Rapsodia 2015</title>    

  </head>
  <body>

    <img src="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/img/lookbook/<?php echo $th; ?>">

  </body>
</html>
```

As WizKid pointed out, I had to also include the parameters in the og:url and it works!